# I have binary data (presence/absence of birds in different forests) and would like to know if there is a model that includes a random effect

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mixed-models

I have presence absence data for different bird species in different forest blocks as the response variable. As predictor variables I have the size of the forest and the number of trees logged from each forest.

I would like to include forest as a random factor to account for variables we were un able to measure. How best could I do this? Would it be best to use a mixed effect logistic regression?

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking along the right lines. By fitting a mixed effects model with random intercepts for forests, you will account for the repeated measures within forests. That is, observations within each forest will be non-independent, and fitting random intercepts will adjust for this. However, I would not go as far as to say that this will account for variables that you were not able to measure except to the extent that these explain the non-independence within forests (which you will never know). Omitted variable bias is another matter altogether, and can sometimes be diagnosed from analysis of residuals, but fitting random effects will not solve that problem.